# How to get Updated Context in Unity3D Android when app is open from Background?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, background, url-scheme, android-context

I am trying to get URL data when Unity3D android app is open from URL scheme. To get data which is come in URL I have written below in Unity3D :

```
using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
        AndroidJavaObject context = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        String dataString = context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent").Call<String>("getDataString");

            Debug.LogError ("URL Data " +dataString );
```

I am able to get URL data but it always remain same if I am opening app from URL scheme or without URL scheme. So I guess the context is not updating when I am opening the app from background state.

Please provide me some suggestion to come out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Main Activity class

```
@Override 
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
 super.onNewIntent(intent);
 setIntent(intent);
}
```